# How to add Change button to the WiX Toolset (burn) Bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I need to add the Change button to my WiX (burn) Bootstrapper, so that it invoked the change action from the MSI that it's wrapping:

[image]

What markup do I need for that?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen when they click Change? If you want it to show the MSI UI, that's not supported in v3.x.

Comment: @SeanHall I'm not really sure what you mean by that. Can you explain, because the actual MSI that I built using WiX toolset has a change button that works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In WiX v3.x, you have to set the `DisplayInternalUI` attribute to `yes` to show the MSI UI. But the only time that the bundle can show the MSI's internal UI is during Install. The engine is hardcoded to force any other operation (modify, repair, uninstall, etc) to run silently. You'll have to write your own custom BootstrapperApplication in v3.x if you want the bundle to be able to modify an MSI, and the BA will have to have its own UI to do so.

In v4 (which isn't released yet), you can use wixstdba to show the MSI's internal UI for all operations but there isn't currently support for a Change button like you're asking for. It only supports Repair and Uninstall like in v3.x. No one has asked for that yet, so you might want to create a feature request at https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues. Otherwise, you'd have to create a BAFunctions.dll to customize wixstdba.

The general recommendation for bundles is to use separate MSI's for different features instead of one MSI with all of the features.